# Getting position from class android

Tags: android, class, methods, geolocation, location

I m looking to made a class to get a location to obtain lat and long.
I m calling this class from fragment, this gets the best provider and calls a method to get a location var. I have this variable position, but when I return variable pos, position is null; why? I to pass this variable?

var pos into method it s ok, but when I will return is null.

```
public class locationmng {
public Context context;
private FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationProviderClient;
Location position;


public locationmng(Context c){
    context=c;

}

public Location GetLoc()  {
    if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) 
        context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        String bestProvider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        if (bestProvider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {

            position = getcoarseposition();

            return position;
       }
```

}

```
@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public  Location getcoarseposition() {
   final Location[] pos = new Location[1];
    fusedLocationProviderClient=
      LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    fusedLocationProviderClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener((Activity) context, new 
               OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                         pos[0] =location;
                    }else {
                        Log.i("locmng","not found loc ");
                    }

                }
            });

    Log.i("locationmanager6894","ho trovato "+ a[0].getLongitude()+ "lat: "+ a[0].getLatitude());

    return pos[0];

}
```

Comment: Did you try my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your location sets in `OnSuccessListener<Location>()`, it is not calling at once. So, you set a listener but it will be called only if your location will be obtained. 
So, what you need to do: do all logic defined in `GetLoc()` in your `onSuccess(Location location)` method of your listener.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not all location settings are satisfied. You should prompt the user to change his location settings by using SettingsClient class.
Documentation here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/change-location-settings

Basically you'll have to:

- create a location request

```java
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
}
```

- get current location setting

```java
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();


SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
```

- add task complete listeners to understand if your location settings are ok

```java
task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
        // location requests here.
        // ...
    }
});

task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
            // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
            // by showing the user a dialog.
            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Once you're done with these three steps, you'll be able to get user location